# Why did the author use "remembering" instead of "remember" in "principles that I think are key to remembering"

Tags: prepositions, infinitive-vs-gerund, gerund-clauses

I was watching a video about how to learn new vocabulary more easily, but I was stuck at this sentence spoken by the video author:

> Now I'm starting with three basic principles that I think are key to
>   **remembering** English Vocabulary.

I don't understand why the author used remembering instead of remember after to, is it a special grammar rule in this case or what?

Comment: You certainly need a gerund after the preposition "to" (it is not an infinitive). *Memorising* would have been better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*to* in this case is simply taken as a preposition.

In light of this use, you can replace what is next (together with the gerund) with a noun.

> *Now I'm starting with three basic principles that I think are key to **it**.*